# In if-statement poll() block, function triggered more than once per request

Tags: c, linux, sockets

I tried to write simple server in C that uses poll() for testing there's an incoming request in listening socket and create a thread to serve request. In if-statement block of testing `fds[0].revents & POLLIN` one thread created per request, but `printf` executed more than once per request.

```
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <sys/socket.h>
#include <sys/poll.h>
#include <netinet/in.h>
#include <arpa/inet.h>
#include <pthread.h>
#include <signal.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

struct sockaddr_in serverAddr, clientAddr;
struct pollfd fd[1];
socklen_t clientlen;
pthread_attr_t pattr;
int serverfd, optval = 1;

void *accreq(void *);
void make_request_thread();
void sig_handler(int);

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
  signal(SIGINT, sig_handler);

  serverAddr.sin_family = AF_INET;
  serverAddr.sin_port   = htons(80);
  inet_pton(AF_INET, "127.0.0.1", &serverAddr.sin_addr.s_addr);

  serverfd = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, 0);
  setsockopt(serverfd, SOL_SOCKET, SO_REUSEADDR, &optval, sizeof(optval));
  bind(serverfd, (struct sockaddr *)&serverAddr, sizeof(serverAddr));
  listen(serverfd, 5);

  clientlen = sizeof(clientAddr);

  fd[0].fd = serverfd;
  fd[0].events = POLLIN;

  pthread_attr_init(&pattr);
  pthread_attr_setdetachstate(&pattr, PTHREAD_CREATE_JOINABLE);

  while(1)
  {
    if(poll(fd, 1, -1) > 0)
    {
      if(fd[0].revents & POLLIN)
      {
        printf("Hello!\n"); /* Why this function executed more than once per incoming request*/
        make_request_thread();
      }
    }
  }//end while loop

  return 0;
}

void *accreq(void *arg)
{
  int saccfd = accept(serverfd, (struct sockaddr *)&clientAddr, &clientlen), port, rc, wc;

  char buffer[2048], addr[INET_ADDRSTRLEN];

  inet_ntop(AF_INET, &clientAddr.sin_addr.s_addr, addr, INET_ADDRSTRLEN);
  port = ntohs(clientAddr.sin_port);
  printf("[Accept request from %s:%i]\n", addr, port);

  rc = read(saccfd, buffer, sizeof(buffer));
  printf("%s\n", buffer);
  wc = write(saccfd, buffer, strlen(buffer));
  close(saccfd);
  pthread_exit(0);
}

void make_request_thread()
{
  pthread_t thread_acc;
  pthread_create(&thread_acc, &pattr, accreq, NULL);
}

void sig_handler(int signo)
{
  printf("\nCatch signal interrupt\nExiting...\n");
  pthread_attr_destroy(&pattr);
  close(serverfd);
  exit(0);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You have a race condition. The race is between your main thread which will call `poll()` again on the accepting socket, and the spawned thread that will call `accept()` on that socket. If the spawned thread that calls `accept()` wins, then the main thread will block (if there is only one incoming connection). If the main thread wins, the `poll()` call will return immediately, since the socket still has a pending connection waiting to be accepted.

In your code, you don't need to use `poll()` at all. You can simply block on a call to `accept()` and and give the spawned thread the newly created socket to process. If you really want `poll()`, the easiest fix is to call `accept()` in the main thread after `poll()` wakes up, and give the newly created socket to the spawned thread.